# Loop to distort a copy of a base mesh, but the loop keeps distorting the previously used mesh?

Tags: modeling, python, scripting, bmesh

I have three functions:

1. **make_plane()**: creates a subdivided plane, applies smooth shading, adds a subsurf modifier, renames it an moves it to a collection
2. **warp_plane()**: takes a copy of a the plane from the first function, and picks a random vertex and simply moves it along the z-axis a random amount with proportional scaling
3. **make_grid()**: creates an x * y * z grid (currently I'm just testing with 3 x 3 x 1) of planes, each of which should be uniquely warped from the second function.

---

### The Problem

What's happening however, is that the mesh from the original plane is somehow being passed from iteration to iteration, instead of it using a copy of the original. I hope that makes sense. I have been able to use this same process in other projects, but the only difference was that I wasn't dealing directly with *meshes*... I was only changing things like scale and rotation. Is it possible to do this without completely breaking my process? I like having things in functions to make it more modular, so if I can keep a similar structure that would be great!

```
def make_plane():
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(enter_editmode=True, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=subd)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    ob = C.object
    
    shade_smooth(ob) #shades smooth
    sub_smooth(ob) #applies subsurf modifier
    rename_link(ob, 'Master_Plane', 'Base Shapes') #moves to new collection
    bpy.context.active_object.select_set(False)
    shapes.append(ob) #adds to list
    
    C.collection.objects.unlink(ob)
#    C.collection.children['Base Shapes'].hide_viewport = True
    C.collection.children['Base Shapes'].hide_render = True
    print(f'Base Shapes: {len(shapes)}')
    for shape in shapes:
        print(f' --{shape.name}')

def warp_plane(obj):
    z = random.random() #random amount to move vertex
    vertex = random.randint(0, vertices) #random vertex
    prop_size = random.uniform(1.0, 2.0) #amount for proportion size
    
    #logic to select a random vertex
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type = 'VERT')
    me = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    me.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    me.verts[vertex].select = True
    
    #moves vertex
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, z), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=True, proportional_size=prop_size)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.context.active_object.select_set(False)
    
def make_grid():    
    print(f'\nGenerating {width}x{length}x{layers} grid - {width*length*layers} spaces...')
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(length):
            for z in range(layers):
                loc = (x*spacing, y*spacing, z*spacing)
                
                current = shapes[0].copy()   
                
                #currently the ob is being overridden with each successive loop
                #instead of copying our "base" plane
                
                warp_plane(current)
                current.location += Vector(loc)
                
                #change name of cube and mesh
                current.name = f'Plane ({x}, {y}, {z})'
                current.data.name = f'Mesh ({x}, {y}, {z})'
                current.data = current.data.copy()

                #assign a random material (not ready yet)
#                mat = random.choices(materials, weights=mat_weights)[0]
#                current.data.materials.append(mat)
#                print(f'shapes[0]: {shapes[0].name}, {shapes[0].data.name}')
                obs.append(current)
            
    for ob in obs:
        D.collections['Generated'].objects.link(ob)
    
    D.objects['Master_Plane'].hide_set(True)
    #deselects everything    
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
```

### The Result

[image]

You can tell that each plane in the grid essentially modified the copy before it, instead of modifying a "fresh" copy of the plane. Is the following line of code not enough to guarantee a unique copy for the warp_planes() function to work on?

```
current = shapes[0].copy()
```

Thank you for any and all advice!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take note that when you do `current = shapes[0].copy()` you are only copying the object but the mesh data it is pointing to is still the same data block that is why it kept warping the same mesh because you called `warp_plane` too early while it still had the previous mesh.

> **Object.copy()**
> Create a copy of this data-block (not supported for all
> data-blocks)
> Example: `bpy.context.object.copy()`
>
> **Mesh.copy()**
> Create a copy of this data-block (not supported for all data-blocks)
> Example: `bpy.context.object.data.copy()`

Basically you only have to do two (2) things. First, you have to call the `warp_plane` function after the mesh data has been set, preferably inside the `for` loop after it is linked into the view layer. And then you have to set the new copied object as the active object before calling `warp_plane`.

```
for ob in obs:
    D.collections['Generated'].objects.link(ob)
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = ob
    warp_plane(ob)
```

Or directly call these three (3) lines inside the loop that creates the objects. There is no need for a second `for` loop. Here's your complete working code:

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import time
import random
from math import radians
from mathutils import Vector
from os import system

#####################################################
#################### CONSTANTS ######################
#####################################################

#scene & object specific
obs    = []
shapes = []
C      = bpy.context
D      = bpy.data
sce    = C.view_layer

#plane specific
width      = 3
length     = 3
layers     = 1
size     = 1
subd     = 7
vertices = (subd + 2) ** 2 - 1
spacing  = 2

#####################################################
################## SCENE FUNCTIONS ##################
#####################################################

def clean_slate():
    #used to clear system console for easier debugging
    cls = lambda: system('cls')
    cls()

    #delete everything in 3d viewport
    C.scene

    for ob in D.objects:
        if ob.type != 'CAMERA' and ob.type != 'LIGHT':
            D.objects.remove(ob)

    for mesh in D.meshes:
        D.meshes.remove(mesh)

    make_collections()

def make_collections():
    colls_to_keep   = ["Studio", "Base Shapes"]
    colls_to_remake = ["Generated"]

    #remakes old collections
    for idx, coll in enumerate(colls_to_remake):
        if coll in D.collections:
            print(f'Deleting old "{coll}" collection...')
#            C.scene.collection.children.unlink(bpy.data.collections[idx])
            D.collections.remove(bpy.data.collections[idx])
        else:   
            print(f'Creating new "{colls_to_remake[idx]}" collection...')
            new = D.collections.new(coll)
            C.scene.collection.children.link(new)

    #makes collections we only need to make one time
    for idx, coll in enumerate(colls_to_keep):
        if coll in D.collections:
            print(f'{coll} exists already!')
        else:
            print(f'Making new {coll} collection!')
            new = D.collections.new(colls_to_keep[idx])
            C.scene.collection.children.link(new)

def rename_link(ob, name, coll):
    ob.name = name
    ob.data.name = name
    ob.data = ob.data.copy()
    D.collections[coll].objects.link(ob)

def debug():
    #easier way of figuring out what is what
    if C.object == None:
        c_name   = "None"
    else:
        c_name   = C.object.name

    if C.selected_objects == []:
        sel_name = "None"
        sel_mesh = "None"
    else:
        sel_name = C.selected_objects[0].name
        sel_mesh = C.selected_objects[0].data.name

    if C.active_object == None:
        act_name = "None"
        act_mesh = "None"
    else:
        act_name = C.active_object.name
        act_mesh = C.active_object.data.name

    print(f'\n{"*"*15} DEBUG {"*"*15}')
    print(f'   Context Object: {c_name}')
    print(f'    Active Object: {act_name}')
    print(f'      Active Mesh: {act_mesh}')
    print(f'    # of Selected: {len(C.selected_objects)}')
    print(f'  Selected Object: {sel_name}')
    print(f'    Selected Mesh: {sel_mesh}')
    print(f'{"*"*37}\n')

#####################################################
################ MODIFIER FUNCTIONS #################
#####################################################
def shade_smooth(ob, smooth=True):
    for poly in ob.data.polygons:
        poly.use_smooth = smooth

def sub_smooth(ob):
    sub = ob.modifiers.new('Subsurf', 'SUBSURF')
    sub.levels = 2
    sub.render_levels = 2

#####################################################
################# SHAPE FUNCTIONS ###################
#####################################################
def make_plane():
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(enter_editmode=True, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=subd)
    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    ob = C.object

    shade_smooth(ob) #shades smooth
    sub_smooth(ob) #applies subsurf modifier
    rename_link(ob, 'Master_Plane', 'Base Shapes') #moves to new collection
    bpy.context.active_object.select_set(False)
    shapes.append(ob) #adds to list

    C.collection.objects.unlink(ob)
#   C.collection.children['Base Shapes'].hide_viewport = True
    C.collection.children['Base Shapes'].hide_render = True
    print(f'Base Shapes: {len(shapes)}')
    for shape in shapes:
        print(f' --{shape.name}')

def warp_plane(obj):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    z = random.random() #random amount to move vertex
    vertex = random.randint(0, vertices) #random vertex
    prop_size = random.uniform(1.0, 2.0) #amount for proportion size

    #logic to select a random vertex
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type = 'VERT')

    me = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
    me.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    me.verts[vertex].select = True

    #moves vertex
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, 0, z), constraint_axis=(False, False, True), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=True, proportional_size=prop_size)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.context.active_object.select_set(False)

def make_grid():    
    print(f'\nGenerating {width}x{length}x{layers} grid - {width*length*layers} spaces...')
    for x in range(width):
        for y in range(length):
            for z in range(layers):
                loc = (x*spacing, y*spacing, z*spacing)

                ob = shapes[0]

                current = ob.copy()
                current.name = f'Plane ({x}, {y}, {z})'
                current.data = ob.data.copy()
                current.data.name = f'Mesh ({x}, {y}, {z})'
                D.collections['Generated'].objects.link(current)

                warp_plane(current)
                current.location += Vector(loc)

                obs.append(current)

    D.objects['Master_Plane'].hide_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

#####################################################
####################### MAIN ########################
#####################################################
start = time.time()

clean_slate()
make_plane()
make_grid()

end = time.time()
print('\n...Done!')
print(f'Elapsed Time: {round(end-start, 3)}s')
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much! Your explanations were very clear, and have improved my understanding of things! :)

Comment: awesome! glad i could help :)

Answer (score 2):

use
`me = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data.copy())`
to get a copy fo the data instead of pointing to it